# onclick one menu should be open in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want that on click of a main link its sublinks open when i click on any other main link its sublinks open and previous opened closes .at a time only one menu should be open.here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZCrk4/6/

```
<!-- Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Container -->
    <div id="container" class="resolution_800x600">

        <!-- Colonnage -->
        <div id="colonnes" class="clear">

                <!-- Navigation Level 02 -->
                <div id="nav1" class="navigation_02">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#11">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#12">Sub menu 2</a></li>   
                                <li><a href="#13">Sub menu 3</a></li>                       
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#21">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#22">Sub menu 2</a></li>                       
                            </ul>
                        </li>                   
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#31">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="secondary-navigation.html" class="active" title="Sub menu 2 (Current page)">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#33">Sub menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#34">Sub menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#41">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#42">Sub menu 2</a></li>   
                                <li><a href="#43">Sub menu 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /Navigation Level 02 -->

        </div>
        <!-- /Colonnage -->

    </div>
    <!-- /Container -->

</div>
<!-- /Wrapper -->
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid. ul cannot contain div as its child

Comment: @PSL u can see the fiddle ,its perfect

Comment: nah your fiddle has issues as i mentioned above.

Comment: Never assume your code is perfect.

Comment: @PSL my mistake now have a look at a fiddle .Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCrk4/19/)

```
var nav = $('#nav1 > ul > li');
nav.find('li').hide();
nav.click(function () {
    nav.not(this).find('li').hide();
    $(this).find('li').slideToggle();
});
```

or

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCrk4/17/)

```
var nav = $('#nav1 > ul > li');
nav.children('ul').children('li').hide();
nav.click(function () {
    nav.children('ul').children('li').hide();
    $(this).children('ul').children('li').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

JS:

```
$('.navigation_02 li:has("ul") > a').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.navigation_02 a.active').not($this).removeClass('active').next().stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
    $this.addClass('active').next().stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

CSS:

```
.navigation_02 > ul > li ul {
    display:none;
}
.active{
    font-style:bold;
    background-color:#cecece;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ycUe/)**